# Drag and Swap List elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asp-classic, drag-and-drop

I have an unordered list that is populated dynamically from a database. What I would like to do is drag and drop the list items to reorder the list.Ideally the new position of the list item is to be saved to a field within the database. This I can do. What I need help with is the Java Script code that swaps a list item with another.

Below is the code for populating the list. As you can see the page is written in ASP.

```
While not rsAwards.EOF
response.write "<li>" & rsAwards("Award_Name")
%>
<a href='edit_awards.asp?Action=edit&Award_ID=<%=rsAwards("Award_ID")%>'>Edit</a>&nbsp;
<a class="lb" href='action_awards.asp?Action=delete&Award_ID=<%=rsAwards("Award_ID")%>'>Delete</a></li>
<%
rsAwards.MoveNext
Wend
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's super easy!! 1 line of code. just add jquery UI (you don't have to add all of it) and some javascript like this:

```
$("#DivContainingYourliElements").sortable({delay:300,items:".myListElement"});
```

this will make the elements drag and drop sortable

You just need a countaining div to call sortable on, and add a class (here its .mylistElement)  to each li element you want to be sortable

see this
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

as another demo, I used it here.  just log in with username: demo password: demo
then click on the first item and you'll see training path, which is sortable

http://knowledgecity.com/tna/tnaadmin.php

by the way, the "delay" attribut is important. It specifies the different between a click and a "drag".  so here in my case, you can click them, or if you click and hold for 300 miliseconds, then it will go into drag/sort mode.  If they only need to sort, set the delay to 1.

Comment: Thank you AwokeKnowing,the following code id the trick.  
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({ placeholder: "ui-state-highlight" });